# unexpected token 'if' in expression or statement powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server, powershell-3.0, hybrid

I have a .CSV file that I'm filling in some AD info with. The following script is supposed to fill in "Office" on a given users AD properties. The Header in the CSV file with the different "Office" names is called 'office'.

Other Info:

Exchange 2013 Hybrid Server

Forrest Functional Level = 2003 (Just demoted old dc's last week)

All DC's are now 2012 R2.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This used to work with QADuser cmdlets so I simply found the cmdlet/parameter equivilents and changed them.

New script that doesn't work:

```
Import-CSV d:\scripts\ExchangeExportQuery.csv | ForEach-Object {$myOff = $_.Office if ($_.DistinguishedName -ne $null -and ($_.DistinguishedName.StartsWith("CN=")) ) {Get-User -ResultSize   'unlimited' -identity $_.DistinguishedName | foreach-object { Set-User -identity $_.DistinguishedName -Office $myOff}}}
```

Old script that actually worked on old exchange 2007 server with QAD cmdlets:

```
Import-CSV d:\scripts\ExchangeExportQuery.csv | ForEach-Object { 
$myOff = $_.Office
if ($_.DN -ne $null -and ($_.DN.StartsWith("OU=")) ) {
    Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot $_.DN | 
        foreach-object { Set-QADUser -identity $_.DN -Office $myOff}
```

I may be way off here and better off starting from scratch, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is syntax. You either need to make it multiple lines or insert a semicolon to separate commands after `$myOff = $_.Office` and before `If (`.  My suggestion is the following, or make it easier to read:

```
Import-CSV d:\scripts\ExchangeExportQuery.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $myOff = $_.Office 
    if ($_.DistinguishedName -ne $null -and ($_.DistinguishedName.StartsWith("CN=")) ) {
        Get-User -ResultSize   'unlimited' -identity $_.DistinguishedName | foreach-object { 
            Set-User -identity $_.DistinguishedName -Office $myOff
        } #End nested ForEach
    } #End If
} #End Outer ForEach
```